# Laravel passing data to view htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, laravel

```
$Family = family::where('family_id',12)->firstOrFail();
//dd($Family); Works here very well

return view('OkFamily',compact('Family'));
```

in my OkFamily.blade.php
when i try to print this object

```
{{ $Family }} and {{ $Family['name']}} and {{ $Family->name }}
```

htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\WAMP64\www\Family\resources\views\OkFamily.blade.php)

other controllers and views works well except this

Comment: $Family is a Eloquent object, so you should access it's properties, like this:
`{{ $Family->name }}`

Comment: why do you think that line is the offending line? ... can you also include the rest of that error

Comment: @RDev i tried but same result

Comment: @labox which line u mean? {{ $Family }} .... ? when i try this it occurs thats why but dont know why

Comment: the error points to that line number?

Comment: @lagbox no , return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);in C:\WAMP64\www\Family\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php

Comment: please provide the rest of the error message ...."htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string" is only part of it

Comment: @lagbox sure , i updated question with full error message

Comment: you are going to have to provide more code here ... what you have is not causing that error

Comment: @lagbox is it possible that family model cause this error ? becasue i have 24 column and just filled a column in protected $fillabled = ['name',];

Comment: look at your view for any other places `$Family` is referenced

Comment: You can't just print `$Family`, it's an object. `dd($Family)` is working because it's a `var_dump($Family)` and then `die()`

Comment: @HtmHell you can echo `$Family` (if it is a Model) it has a `__toString` method ... it will get converted to a string [json] ... `$Family` doesn't seem to be a Model, seems to be an array for some reason ... assuming that error is actually matching the code, but i feel it is not

Comment: @lagbox , oh sorry u right i found another $Family bottom view that cause error i forgot to comment that , Thankssss lagbox ,answer the question ill accept , thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to guess because it seems the code isn't quite matching up with the error that this error is coming from a different place potentially in that view.

Its possible you are setting `$Family` to an array unintentionally though, but more likely this error is coming from a different line in that view as Eloquent Models are objects (that have a `__toString` so they can be converted to strings [as JSON]) and not arrays.

Good Luck.